# webRTC example does not working after downloading source?

Tags: webrtc

I am looking to use webRTC for my college project. The example(http://simpl.info/getusermedia/) works nice (asks the permission to access the webcamera) whenever i access them from internet but after i download the source(even from github) it does not work, it does not even ask the permission for accessing the camera. any help? Thanks.

Comment: You need to host it(even locally) and access it that way. Are you doing that? Or are you simply opening up the files?

Comment: Yep I needed to host the project. Previously I was just opening the file. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebRTC API does not work unless it is being hosted. Simply opening the html files and running the scripts will not work.

So, I bet if you host it(Apache, VisualStudio, etc), it will work just fine.